# How to show NEW post content in post editor?

Tags: post-content

In my `functions.php` I have:

```
 global $wpdb;
 $wpdb->update( 
   $wpdb->posts, 
   array('post_content' => $newcontent), 
   array('ID' => $post_id) 
 );
```

this code updates the `post_content` in the WP DB with my `$newcontent` when I publish a post.
In fact I can see the modified content inside the DB and of course I can see it with:

```
 echo get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
```

The issue is that (after publish and update) the post editor continues to show the *old* content!
In a few words... I need a way to force the editor to show the `$newcontent`, the one stored into the DB (after publish).
Any ideas?

Comment: P.S. Of course if I exit from the post and then I go there again, I see the new content!

Comment: Please provide full or at least sufficient context to your question to make it answerable. For example, show how the code snippet you posted actually is implemented.

Comment: Ah you want a live update? That functionality isn't present in WordPress Core, you'll need to build it yourself. Also, instead of changing the database directly, use `wp_update_post` so that the necessary caches and actions and filters are called, always avoid using direct database queries

Comment: Please mark the answer that provided a solution as such, so the question does not stay open forever. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try wp update post function:

```
// Update post 37 for example
  $my_post = array(
  'ID'           => 37,
  'post_title'   => 'This is the post title.',
  'post_content' => 'This is the updated content.',
  );

// Update the post into the database
  wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post

Comment: Yes, it was the wp_update_post!!
Thank you Tom, Prosti and thank you Shady Alset you save me!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what is your scenario, but I think you need to refresh the WordPress editor. If you did that try to update the post since it is cached. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post